# How to change the root directory of vim?

Tags: working-directory

My vim is installed in `D:\Vim\vim82`, but somehow `$VIM` points to the directory `D:\Vim\vim82\vim.exe\vim82`.

Therefore when I startup vim all the features that need to access folders in the root directory will search in a non-existent directory `vim.exe\vim82`.

For example when I open VimTutor it says can't open file `D:\Vim\vim82\vim.exe/tutor/tutor.vim`

I tried reinstalling vim in folder `vim.exe` and it worked. But I'd like to install it in folder vim.

So would anyone help me to change the root directory please?

Comment: How did you install your Vim? It looks like this was set incorrectly when your Vim binary was built... Did you compile it yourself? Otherwise, where did tou get your Vim package from? Please include more information such as the version of Vim you're using, etc. Also, is it possible that you're setting `$VIM` in your Windows environment? If you run a command such as `set` or `echo %VIM%` in a command prompt (sorry, I haven't done Windows in a while, so not completely sure what the exact commands should be), does it return something unexpected?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am setting my vim in a Windows environment. So I Installed it with self-installing executable. The version is vim8.2 x64. When I run command **echo $VIM** it shows the directory **D:\Vim\vim82\vim.exe**. But the vim.exe directory doesn't exit. I want $VIM just to be ''D:\Vim\vim82''.

Comment: I guess my question is whether it's possible that you're setting the `VIM` environment variable in Windows explicitly to point at the binary... Can you check that from a command prompt (outside of Vim)?

Comment: I think `$VIM` should actually be `D:\Vim`; the `vim82` gets added automatically. Not sure how to properly set that in Windows, but just FYI :-) Back in the day you could set it in system settings somewhere, and I think the Vim installer added it automatically IIRC

Comment: PS welcome to [vi.se]!